# How to migrate an existing column to a new column in SQL but with values mapping to new data type?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `bit` column in my table. I want to add a new column of `int` (an enum). No problem. However I want to migrate the data in the `bit` column to map to the new `integer` column.

Specifically, I would like any rows in the bit column that were true (1) to be mapped in the new column to the `int` value 2.

Any that were false (0) in the `bit` column, I would like mapped to `int` value 1.

Any help on the syntax of this logic would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a CASE expression. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql

Comment: Thanks - that's what I need.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: MS SQL Server. Didn't realise I'd tagged MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated correctly in the comments, you can use a `CASE` clause in your migration script to serve whichever mapping logic you may want to implement. See [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql).

Sample syntax:

```
CASE 
    WHEN column = [value_to_map] THEN [mapped_value]
    WHEN column = [value_to_map] THEN [mapped_value]
    ...
ELSE
    [fallback_value]
END AS [some_alias]
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, that was clearer to my user case than the official documentation

Comment: I'm glad I could help @Marcus

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET NewCol = 
    CASE oldCol 
        WHEN True THEN 2 
        WHEN False THEN 1
    END
```